# Measure power & energy usage in tapped line

Tags: ac, current-measurement, measurement, power-measurement

Here is the schematic of the circuit in question:
[image]

The horizontal lines are from the AC mains. Ammeters and wattmeters are connected at any 2 points in the main lines. I am trying to detect if the line is tapped in between, and if tapped, how much power is flowing through that tapped line.

**My idea:**

1. Measure the current at 2 points and check if they are the same. If they are not the same, it means the line is being tapped.
2. Measure the power at 2 points and subtract them to get power flowing through the tapped line.

Am I right in my approach? If not, how can I achieve my objective? Please note that connecting any meter at the tapped line directly is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Measuring power at each point is enough.
You will have a very small power loss from the line section between the meters, and from each meter.

Current comparisons would at least need to measure voltage and phase and maybe take account of waveform, as eg a reactive load will vary these at least somewhat.
A power meter handles all these as a "vector sum".

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to detect if there is a "tapped" current is to use a current transformer like this: -

[image]

If the neutral wiring on one side is inaccessible to the other side you could use two current transformers and wire the secondaries in series.

The method above is a difference measurement of two currents and, can tell you the magnitude of any "tapped" current.

Comment: This is actually pretty much exactly how GFCIs (RCDs if you're british) work.

Comment: @Hearth precisely

Comment: That  overcomes the issue I mention of an ammeter at each point. Odds are his two points are somewhat separated and this may be inconvenient (but probably doable). It would be interesting to try a "signal linked" system where the measurement from one sensor was sent by "wireless" of some sort. Allowance for delay needed, and ... .